# How to bind datasource property from env variables Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, datasource, application.properties

How to bind datasource property from env variables Spring boot

I have some property

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

and i need to fill db connection parameters from env variable

```
java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DdbUrl=URL -DdbUser=USER -DdbPassword=PASSWORD
```

how can i do this?
binding `like spring.datasource.url=${URL}`  doesnt works(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass your parameters like:

```
--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:xx:xx:xxx
```

Instead of -DparamName

Comment: it works! but now nowi need skip tests during datasource autoconfiguration when I building applicatipn